# Sidekiq Workers Not Expiring Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sidekiq

Our architecture has dedicated servers that only run Sidekiq worker processes, i.e. there is no app server.  We have some model caching going on - all calls to Rails.cache inside models specify an `expires_in` value but the expired caches are not being cleared.

Occasionally the disk inodes fill up becasue the `tmp/cache` is never getting cleaned up.

The fix is simple - run a cron job for `tmp:cache:clear`, but maybe the community can offer some guidance and understanding on this scenario w/r to how Rails clears expired model cache keys especially when Sidekiq workers are the only thing running on a server.

Comment: So, the cache is on disk? Not redis?

Comment: That is correct - we are using disk caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expiration is handled by the Cache Store, if it supports such thing. Rails' default cache store (file store) is simple, it doesn't know much. What you are doing, manually clearing the cache is what the docs (below) suggest.

You can try [Redis](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore) or [Memcached](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore), they know how to expire things.

An excerpt from [ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore)

**2.4 ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore**

> This cache store uses the file system to store entries. The path to the directory where the store files will be stored must be specified when initializing the cache.
>
> As the cache will grow until the disk is full, it is recommended to periodically clear out old entries.

> This is the default cache store implementation (at "#{root}/tmp/cache/") if no explicit config.cache_store is supplied.

And another one from [ActiveSupport::Cache::Store](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store)

> :expires_in - This option sets an expiration time in seconds for the cache entry, if the cache store supports it, when it will be automatically removed from the cache.

Comment: In our code, all of the calls to Rails.cache methods set a value for :expires_in therefore all of the cache keys should have an expiration set.  When the server does not run a Rails application (it only runs Sidekiq workers), it appears that Rails never automatically removes expired items from the cache.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you set expires in as long as the file store doesn't know how to handle it. In the the answer there are excerpts from the docs.

Comment: Please update with those models and how sidekiq runs the jobs.